# Using "require group" with mod_authn_dbm in Apache HTTPD 2.4

Tags: apache, authorization, basic-authentication, httpd.conf

I am using Apache HTTPD 2.4 and I've decided it's time for me to move from `mod_authn_file` to `mod_authn_dbm`.  I've got it mostly working but it won't check my `AuthDBMUserFile` for group information.  I've googled it and it appears that this kind of functionality should still be available, via `mod_authz_dbm` which I've now included.  The documentation for `mod_authz_dbm` makes it appear that you just have to use the `AuthDBMGroupFile` directive as in my configuration below:

```
<Directory "C:/Apache24/site/requests">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secure Area"
AuthBasicProvider dbm
AuthDBMUserFile site/data/users
AuthDBMGroupFile site/data/users
Require group admin
</Directory>
```

(Don't worry, `site/data` is not accessible via the webserver!)

However, even though the directive is clearly known (`httpd -t` doesn't complain and the server starts OK), it is either being ignored or something else is trying to find a different group file.  The error I see in the log file is:

```
AH01664: No group file was specified in the configuration
```

Does my configuration look incomplete somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer via the [Apache HTTPD Users Mailing List](http://httpd.apache.org/userslist.html) courtesy of Eric Covener, who says:

> mod_authz_dbm responds to Require dbm-group (and dbm-file-group) only in 2.4 which seems to be a change from 2.2.

So my configuration should have been:

```
<Directory "C:/Apache24/site/requests">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secure Area"
AuthBasicProvider dbm
AuthDBMUserFile site/data/users
AuthDBMGroupFile site/data/users
Require dbm-group admin
</Directory>
```

I have tried this and it does exactly what I wanted.  Many thanks Eric!